# How to tell who bought subscription

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

As a CSP partner, we currently use the MSOL cmdlets for our automation process. We are currently switching our implementation to Microsoft Graph API.

MSOL offers, through `Get-MsolSubscription`, a way to know if a subscription has been bought by us or by another service provider. To know that, we inspect the `OwnerObjectId` attribute and if the value is set with our Id, we know it has been bought to us. Otherwise this attribute is empty.

It seems that Microsoft Graph API does not support this feature. [SubscribedSku](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/subscribedsku)  does not seem to expose the feature we are looking for.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand properly, you want to get a list of subscriptions by order for Azure CSP integration.

You can retrieve a collection of Azure Cloud Solution Provider (Azure CSP) subscription resources that correspond to an order. To retrieve a resource, you can use PowerShell, C#, or REST API commands.

**Powershell guide**

```
$customer = Get-PCCustomer -tenantid '<tenant id GUID>'
Get-PCSubscription -tenantid $customer.id -orderid '<order id GUID>'
```

**C# SDK guide**

To get a list of subscriptions by order, use your **IAggregatePartner.Customers** collection and call the **ById()** method. Then call the **Subscriptions** property, followed by the **ByOrderId()** method. Finish by calling **Get()** or **GetAsync()**.

```
// IAggregatePartner partnerOperations;
// var selectedCustomerId as string;
// string orderID;

ResourceCollection<Subscription> customerSubscriptions = partnerOperations.Customers.ById(selectedCustomerId).Subscriptions.ByOrder(orderID).Get();
```

**REST API Example**

```
GET https://api.partnercenter.microsoft.com/v1/customers/{customer-tenant-id}/subscriptions?order_id={id-for-order} HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer <token>
Accept: application/json
MS-RequestId: 16fee928-dc2c-412f-adbb-871f68babf16
MS-CorrelationId: c49004b1-224f-4d86-a607-6c8bcc52cfdd
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

See  more details in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-solution-provider/integration/place-orders/get-subscriptions-by-order).

Comment: Not exactly. The use case is to inspect the subscription of a tenant that has bot been bought at our company. By inspecting I mean checking the quantity included in the subscription and it's state. With MSOL, we can inspect for example all the subscriptions of O365_BUSINESS_PREMIUM.

Comment: @NormandBedard , well ,these examples do not get the SKU information which you want,but it get the status and other details of the subscriptions. As I known, there is no way to using Graph API to get all the information that you want directly.